# Cast Set to Iterable

Tags: java, generics

I have this static method:

```
  static <V, T, E> void GroupToSets(
    final Iterable<T> items,
    final Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<Map<String, Set<V>>, E> f) {

    final HashMap<String, Set<V>> results = new HashMap<>();
    final Iterator<T> iterator = items.iterator();

    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
      f.done(null, results);
      return;
    }


    RunMap((Map<String, Iterable<V>>)results, f);

  }
```

And I am calling this:

```
  private static <T, V, E> void RunMap(
    final Map<String, Iterable<V>> results,
    final Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<Map<String, Iterable<V>>, E> f) { ... }
```

the problem is for some reason I can't cast a `Set<V>` to `Iterable<V>`...I am looking for a supertype for both `List<V>` and `Set<V>`, I thought Iterable would do that but apparently not?

The error I am getting is:

> `Inconvertible types; cannot cast`
>
> `'java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.Set<V>>' to`
>
> `'java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Iterable<V>>'`

I am also trying to cast `List<V>` to `Iterable<V>` as I mentioned I am looking for a supertype for both List and Set..maybe just use Collection?

**Update**, I tried using:

```
final Map<String, Collection<V>> results
```

instead of

```
final Map<String, Iterable<V>> results
```

I get the same problem.

Comment: can you modify the `RunMap` method?

Comment: Yep I sure can, good to clarify that tho thanks

Comment: I cleaned up the question a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `RunMap` declaration to:

```
private static <V, E, T extends Iterable<V>> void RunMap(
    final Map<String, T> results,
    final Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<Map<String, T>, E> f) {
```

Generics in Java are not covariance, it means when `RunMap` expects a `Map<String, Iterable<V>>` you cannot pass to it a `Map<String, Set<V>>` instance.

To solve this you can use a bounded wildcard `? extends Vector<V>`, however there is a correlation between the two `RunMap` arguments. The type of the values in the the two maps must be the same, therefore you need to define a method type `T extends Iterable<V>` and use it when defining the type of the method arguments: `Map<String, T>` and `Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<Map<String, T>, E>`.

You can make the declaration a bit shorter by defining `M extends Map<String, ? extends Iterable<V>>`:

```
private static <V, E, M extends Map<String, ? extends Iterable<V>>> void RunMap(
    final M results,
    final Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<M, E> f) {
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Map<String, Set<V>>` is not a `Map<String, Iterable<V>>`, because you can invoke this code on the latter, but not the former:

```
results.put("", new ArrayList<>());
```

and then you have broken type safety, because code using a `Map<String, Set<V>>` expects all values to be Sets.

You need to add a bound to the parameter in the method signature:

```
final Map<String, ? extends Iterable<V>> results
```

which precludes putting into `results`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the definition to:

```
static <V, T, E> void GroupToSets(
            final Iterable<T> items,
            final Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<Map<String, ? extends Iterable<V>>, E> f) {

        final Map<String, ? extends Set<V>> results = new HashMap<>();
        final Iterator<T> iterator = items.iterator();

        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
            f.done(null, results);
            return;
        }


        RunMap(results, f);

    }

    static <T, V, E> void RunMap(
            final Map<String, ? extends Iterable<V>> results,
            final Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<Map<String, ? extends Iterable<V>>, E> f) {

    }
```

Comment: I tried that, I get this problem `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.HashSet<V>', required: '? extends java.lang.Iterable<V>' `

Comment: @AlexanderMills, you need to change from `RunMap((Map<String, Iterable<V>>)results, f);` to this `RunMap(results, f);` remove casting, it works fine